# Install servlet 3.1 on Websphere liberty core manually

Tags: websphere-liberty

I would like to install servlet 3.1 on Websphere Liberty Core 8.5.5.7.
I cannot reach the the Liberty repository so I can't use :

```
installUtility install servlet-3.1
```

How can I install servlet-3.1 manually without connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a other computer with Liberty Profile 8.5.5.2 or higher and internet connection.

You can download in this computer the needed features with featureManager utility with --downloadOnly option.

```
bin/featureManager install feature_shortName1 feature_shortName2 --downloadOnly=[all|required*|none]
```

You can specify a local destination directory with --location optinon.

Then copy the download directory in your computer without internet connection and install the feature:

```
bin/featureManager install feature_shortName1 feature_shortName2 --location=directoryPath
```

More information in:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/t_install_assets_cmd.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

you can download the .esa file form IBM website then install it with the command

```
installUtility install localrepo3\com.ibm.websphere.appserver.servlet-3.1.esa
```

where localrepo3/  is a directory in the bin directory of WebSphere